# uploading large files (mp4) to IIS 7.5 gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, upload

I made a website on which i need to be able to upload video files and it has worked for quite a while. However after a while it just stopped working and now it will give me the following IIS error message when i upload a video. Images do work (possibly due to their smaller size). I use an html form with PHP server sided script to upload.

[image]

I have already set the user permissions for the entire inetpub to allow all actions for the IIS user.

If you have any idea what it could be PLEASE tell me, have been trying to fix this for weeks now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have `upload_max_filesize` and/or `post_max_size` values set too low in `php.ini`.

Comment: nope they are set to 1024M and 3000 seconds where applicable, and when this is the problem the server will just give an empty $_FILES array, not an error.

Comment: Have you verified the php settings took effect by looking at phpinfo() ?

Comment: Yes, they all took effect.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In addition to the other standard answers here, if you are using FastCGI click FastCGI settings from home in IIS.  Then check the timeouts for ACTIVITY, REQUEST, IDLE.  I increased these to 300 seconds and I then could upload larger files.

Comment: Worked for us. Good to keep in mind if you are using Laravel since it requires FastCGI in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a project that required increasing upload size limits in IIS7 as well. I was trying to get to 10 GB...not possible with IIS7 ([MS forums for more info](https://forums.iis.net/t/1210714.aspx)).

If you only need files <= 2 GB, you should follow the others advice (Chris and Janne's answers), but if you are looking to get larger files uploaded, **IIS7/7.5 will only allow you to go up to 4 GB (4294967295 Bytes)**, but  you won't be able to use all 4 GBs...the most I was able to increase it too was 1/2 that.

In your web.config file, you can change the maxAllowedContentLength (More info [here](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm)):

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The above edit will allow you to get 2 GB uploads in combination with changing your php.ini file. You may want to increase your script execution time within your script using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`, as larger files may take longer.

Good luck and all the best!

Comment: This worked for me, the defualt value is set to 30MB so i had to increase the value.

Answer (score 0):

Dragon, Do you have "Request Filtering" module installed?  Within this module, if you edit the feature settings (on the right sidebar) you'll find a "Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)" setting.  That is the only other setting I can think of that might cause this.

[image: Request Filtering Settings]

Comment: This is all set to 512000000 (512MB) the file i'm uploading is 50 MB, that is not the problem.

Comment: Not to mention that the error seems to single out the PHP handler.  As an aside, 512000000 KB is 488 MB :-)

Comment: Yea i know, its kinda like HDD's.. They promise you 512GB but in reality you have like 460.. (the thiefs!)